# requests returning HTTP 404 when logging in after POST

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape this course review website for my college, but to do so I need to log in. I think I'm doing everything right in the login process:

1. The payload is complete with all of the relevant information. I used inspect element and network to verify that I hadn't missed any input fields and get_authenticity_token is successfully scraping the relevant string.
2. Maybe I'm doing something wrong in my header? I just copied someone else's code for that. Might not even need a header.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) '
    'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36')}

payload = {'email':'person@email.com', 
           'password':'secret',
           'utf8':'✓',
           'commit': 'Sign In'
         }

def get_authenticity_token(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    token = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'authenticity_token'})
    if not token:
        print('could not find `authenticity_token` on login form')
    return token.get('value').strip()



s = session.get("https://pomonastudents.org/login")
payload.update({
    'authenticity_token': get_authenticity_token(s.text)
    })

s = session.post("https://pomonastudents.org/login", data=payload)

print(s.text)
print(payload)
```

Why might this not be working? What steps can I take to investigate possible causes?
edit: fixed awkward wording and added last sentence.

Comment: "*What possible reasons could this not be working?*" There are an innumerable number of reasons this could be not working; most often here we see sites with other security measures both on the client and server side that deliberately hamstring this type of automated scraping. With only the detail you've provided in your question, it's very difficult to say.

Comment: The login button on the page seems to be going to `/login/credentials`, not `/login`.  And what's the special character in the `'utf8'` field?

Comment: Not sure what's with the ```utf8``` field. I just noticed it was there so I added it. When I changed the url to ```/login/credentials``` I get a 422 error.  Progress?

Comment: Include `X-CSRF-Token` within headers. Moreover, you are sending post requests to the wrong url. The correct one should be `https://pomonastudents.org/login/credentials`

Comment: I included ```X-CSRF-Token``` within headers and corrected the url. I am now getting an HTTP 422 response.

Answer (score 0):

The following is how I meant. Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'utf8': '✓',
    'authenticity_token': '',
    'email': 'person@email.com',
    'password': 'secret',
    'commit': 'Sign In'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
    res = s.get("https://pomonastudents.org/login")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    payload['authenticity_token'] = soup.select_one("[name='authenticity_token']")["value"]
    s.headers['X-CSRF-Token'] = soup.select_one("[name='csrf-token']")["content"]
    resp = s.post('https://pomonastudents.org/login/credentials',data=payload)
    print(resp.status_code)
```